# How can I remove "Top stories" from Google search results?

Tags: google-search

When I search Google eg for "Russia", I get a box of news results on top:

[image: Google results for Russia]

Is there any setting or Chrome extension that can remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Click **Tools** (below the search box, near the magnifier icon) > **Verbatim**

Related

- [How do I force Google Search to use the word I type with no "corrections"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19658/88163)
- [Way to disable Google's "Results for Similar Searches"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50537/88163)
- [Is Google search engine excludes some results to be shown?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103244/88163)
- [Where to find a list of Google search operators?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122235/88163)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a method that would work ongoingly, is there a way of making verbatim the default search type?

Comment: @ak0000 AFAIK there isn't... but quote enclosing might work i.e. `"russia"`